# premake5: how to set runtime library to Multithreaded DLL (/MD) in vs2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, autocad, premake

```
kind "SharedLib"
language "C++"
defines "DLL_EXPORT"
targetname "read_cad_file"
targetextension ".arx"
```

I am developing using objectARX, and I want to compile my project using **premake5** and **vs2015**. Some of the settings in the script is as the above.
Under this setting, in properties->C/C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library, the runtime library is **Multithreaded Debug(/MTd)**.
I would like to ask how to change it to **Multithreaded DLL (/MD)** using premake5? Thanks a lot:)

Comment: You are still on the Debug configuration, switch to the Release configuration.

Answer (score 7):

In order to change the runtime library in premake, you need to use two keywords - `staticruntime` and `runtime`.

To use /MT in premake:

```
staticruntime "on"
runtime "Release"
```

To use /MTd in premake:

```
staticruntime "on"
runtime "Debug"
```

To use /MD in premake:

```
staticruntime "off"
runtime "Release"
```

To use /MDd in premake:

```
staticruntime "off"
runtime "Debug"
```

Answer (score 3):

The key you are looking for is [`staticruntime`](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/staticruntime). While it should be off by default, you can also turn it off explicitly

As in

```
staticruntime "Off"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   configuration "Debug"
      buildoptions "/MDd"
   configuration "Release"
      buildoptions "/MD"
   configuration {}
```

Comment: Can you explain how and why these options will solve OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the static or DLL versions of the runtime. But debug and release should be switchable by the `runtime` keyword. See:

https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/runtime

Comment: I tried the keyword runtime before, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Post the full premake file then. If it really "does not work" you should file a bug at the premake project.

Comment: I post the full premake file in the answer below, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, my project isn't a shared lib, but an exe.

What I added was the following to the 'filter' section:

```
filter "configurations:Debug"
    architecture "x86_64"
    links {"libprotobufd"}
    defines {"DEBUG"}
    symbols "On"
    libdirs { baseLibPath .. "debug" } -- baseLibPath was defined elsewhere
    postbuildcommands {}
    debugdir "$(TargetDir)"
    flags {"staticruntime"} -- this is what worked for me
```

I'm not sure if that will solve your problem, but give it a go?

I'm still relatively new to premake, so take this with a grain of salt.

Answer (score -1):

```
project "read_cad_file"
  kind "SharedLib"
  language "C++"
  defines "DLL_EXPORT"
  targetname "read_cad_file"
  targetextension ".arx"
  files "*.cpp"
  files "*.def"
  files "*.lua"
  sysincludedirs "../../../third_party/object_arx/inc-x64/"     
  sysincludedirs "../../../third_party/object_arx/inc/"
  includedirs "../../../third_party/object_arx/inc/"
  includedirs "../../../third_party/object_arx/inc-x64/"
  libdirs "../../../third_party/object_arx/lib-x64/"
  links "ac1st22.lib"
  links "acad.lib"
  links "accore.lib"
  links "acdb22.lib"
  links "acge22.lib"
  links "acgiapi.lib"
  links "acui22.lib"
  links "adui22.lib"
  links "advapi32.lib"
  links "rxapi.lib"
```

This is the full premake file.